# Difference between 2 ways working with pipes using ARGF?

Tags: ruby, command-line, pipeline

Using ARGF I can create Ruby programs that respect pipelines. Suppose, I to constantly read new entries:

```
$ tail -f log/test.log | my_prog
```

I can do this using:

```
ARGF.each_line do |line|
 ...
end
```

Also, I found another way:

```
while input = ARGF.gets
  input.each_line do |line|
   ...
  end
end
```

Looks like, both variants do the same thing or there is a difference between them? If so, what is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're calling [`each_line`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-each_line) on a string with a single line.

Comment: BTW, you can simply call `while input = gets` to read from stdin, or even shorter: `while gets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stefan mentioned, you did a little mistake in second case. Proper way of using "ARGF.gets" approach in your case will look like:

```
while input = ARGF.gets
  # input here represents a line
end
```

If you rewrite the second example as above, you will not have difference in behavior.

Actual difference you may notice between [`ARGF#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/ARGF.html#method-i-gets) and [`ARGF#each_line`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-each_line) is in semantics: `each_line` accepts block or returns enumerator and `gets` returns a next line if it is available.

Another option is to use [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets). Beware it's behavior may differ from `ARGF#gets` in some cases, especially if you change a separator:

> A separator of nil reads the entire contents, and a zero-length separator reads the input one paragraph at a time, where paragraphs are divided by two consecutive newlines.

But for reading (and then printing) constantly from stdin you may use it as follows:

```
print while gets
```